# writing minitests for create and update api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I am very new to rails and I am writing test cases for my rails application.
Suppose I have a code like this -

```
class EmailController < ApplicationController

  def new
    render :layout => false
  end

  def create
    begin
      process_email = ProcessEmail.new(params)
      process_email.perform
    rescue EmailHelper::HtmlSanitizerTimeoutError, EmailHelper::NokogiriTimeoutError => e
      NewRelic::Agent.notice_error(e, account_id: Account.current.id, subject: params[:subject])
      process_email.mark_email_on_timeout
    end
    render layout: 'email'
  end

 def update 
   ----
 end
```

> I have written test cases for create and update. But how do I write
>   test cases that will execute the rescue part??

`This is my db 
(class abc < ActiveRecord::Base)` 

`this is my controller class 
(class abcsController < ApiApplicationController).`

**I have written minitest like this** `

```
def test_raise_exception 
    params = {"a":"b"} 
    item = abc.new(params) 
    raises_exception = -> { raise ArgumentError.new } 
    item.stub :create, raises_exception do 
    assert_raises(ArgumentError) { post :create } 
    end 
end`
```

This is error which is coming -

> NameError: NameError: undefined method create' for class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stub a method to raise an error using Ruby MiniTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990622/how-do-i-stub-a-method-to-raise-an-error-using-ruby-minitest)

Comment: This is my db (class abc < ActiveRecord::Base)
this is my controller class (class abcsController < ApiApplicationController). I have written minitest like this
    def test_raise_exception
      params = {"a":"b"}
      item = abc.new(params)
      raises_exception = -> { raise ArgumentError.new }
      item.stub :create, raises_exception do
        assert_raises(ArgumentError) { post :create }
      end
    end

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev  its giving errors. NameError:         NameError: undefined method `create' for class `#<Class:0x00005599778f3480>'

Comment: Please add details by editing the question instead of comments. They are not readable.